# Need to move even and odd files to seperate folder

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

I've got a folder with about 2000 pictures (.tif) from a two-high-speed-camera measuring system. Half of the pictures are from one camera with filenames *number*_0.tif, the other are from the other camera *number*_1.tif. The numbers are ordered and theres always a _0 and a _1 copy of the same number (a picture taken at the same instant with the left and right camera). There's also some other files in the folder.
I want to make a batch file that will create two folders, left and right, and separate out the _0 and the _1 files. The rest of the files in the folder must be left in the original folder. I don't have much time to learn command prompt syntax and codes; I tried a construction with xcopy and then except *_1.tif, but this didn't work. I'm on a windows 7 operating system.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use PowerShell or scripts in another "mightier" language than the command prompt batch script:

1. Find all files that either end with _0 or _1 and copy them to another directory
2. Loop through all files in the second directory and move every second to a third directory

Answer (score 0):

```
move *_1.tif "oddfolder"
move *_0.tif "evenfolder"
```